# Livecharts2 - Move the Price to right side on Candlestick chart

Tags: avaloniaui, livecharts, avalonia

I'm using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Avalonia and I would like to know how can I put the Price on right side instead left side on candlestick?

Not WPF. I'm using Avalonia.

Example:

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sexWI.png)

AXAML:

```
   <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding Series}" XAxes="{Binding XAxes}" ZoomMode="X" >
   </lvc:CartesianChart>
```

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using LiveChartsCore;
using LiveChartsCore.Defaults;
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView;

namespace ViewModelsSamples.Financial.BasicCandlesticks;

public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        var data = new FinancialData[]
        {
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 1), 523, 500, 450, 400),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 2), 500, 450, 425, 400),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 3), 490, 425, 400, 380),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 4), 420, 400, 420, 380),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 5), 520, 420, 490, 400),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 6), 580, 490, 560, 440),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 7), 570, 560, 350, 340),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 8), 380, 350, 380, 330),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 9), 440, 380, 420, 350),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 10), 490, 420, 460, 400),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 11), 520, 460, 510, 460),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 12), 580, 510, 560, 500),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 13), 600, 560, 540, 510),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 14), 580, 540, 520, 500),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 15), 580, 520, 560, 520),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 16), 590, 560, 580, 520),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 17), 650, 580, 630, 550),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 18), 680, 630, 650, 600),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 19), 670, 650, 600, 570),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 20), 640, 600, 610, 560),
            new(new DateTime(2021, 1, 21), 630, 610, 630, 590)
        };

        Series = new ISeries[]
        {
            new CandlesticksSeries<FinancialPointI>
            {
                Values = data
                    .Select(x => new FinancialPointI(x.High, x.Open, x.Close, x.Low))
                    .ToArray()
            }
        };

        XAxes = new[]
        {
            new Axis
            {
                LabelsRotation = 15,
                Labels = data
                    .Select(x => x.Date.ToString("yyyy MMM dd"))
                    .ToArray()
            }
        };
    }

    public Axis[] XAxes { get; set; }

    public ISeries[] Series { get; set; }
}

public class FinancialData
{
    public FinancialData(DateTime date, double high, double open, double close, double low)
    {
        Date = date;
        High = high;
        Open = open;
        Close = close;
        Low = low;
    }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Open { get; set; }
    public double Close { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
}
```

I didn't find on Internet a reference how to move it to Right side.

Versions:
Avalonia 11.0.4
LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Avalonia 2.0.0 rc1.2

Comment: Somehow you need to work with the `YAxis.Position = End`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a YAxis and set it's Position property, you may optionally also find a need to reduce the left/right pad if you choose to label the axis as it tends to want to put it far away from the actual chart (YMMV).  See the snippet below.

```cs
new Axis()
{
    Name = "My Y Axis",
    Position = LiveChartsCore.Measure.AxisPosition.End,
    NamePadding = new Padding(0, 10, 0, 20),
}
```